# Why re-install repository in forge laravel change data in env?

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, environment, forge

Before I re-install my repository in the forge laravel, I backup my env file

After I install my repository in the forge laravel, the data in env had changed

There are 3 keys that changed, that are `APP_KEY, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD`

What I want to ask is :

Do I keep using `APP_KEY, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD` like in my backup env or I use `APP_KEY, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD` new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `composer.json` file contains some scripts that are run after installing a project:

```
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate"
    ],
```

If `.env` does not exist in the project root, it will copy `.env.example` to `.env`. After that, `php artisan key:generate` is run which sets the new `APP_KEY`.

The `APP_KEY` doesn't matter so much when you're dealing with a new project and have no encrypted data. `DB_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD` you probably need your old values if you have a database already you want to reconnect to.

From Laravel Docs:

> **Application Key**
>
> The next thing you should do after installing Laravel
>   is set your application key to a random string. If you installed
>   Laravel via Composer or the Laravel installer, this key has already
>   been set for you by the php artisan key:generate command.
>
> Typically, this string should be 32 characters long. The key can be
>   set in the .env environment file. If you have not renamed the
>   .env.example file to .env, you should do that now. **If the application
>   key is not set, your user sessions and other encrypted data will not
>   be secure!**

Comment: So, if I use `APP_KEY`(old app key) from my env backup file, it will not be problematic?

Comment: I will be fine to use in a new installation. Keep in mind your `APP_KEY` is used for encryption, so it should always be unique for each application, but in your case, since you re-installing your application, there should be no issues with re-using the old one.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Seems I will keep using the old `APP_KEY`

Comment: I actually want to use a new `APP_KEY` for security. But I am afraid it will be problematic

Comment: How so? Do you have encrypted data from a previous installation you need to access? I have regenerated the app key many times on different projects for various reasons (mostly me forgetting to back up the .env file) and never had any problems.

Comment: No. I just want to anticipate it. It seems okay to use old or new `APP_KEY`